# I keep getting an error on my details page when it is tapped

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I created a Home Screen and it extends a stateful widget.
The Home Screen is supposed to host a List which is loaded from firebase.
Here is the code for the Home Screen;

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fmc_login_app/src/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Details Page'),
      ),
      body: ListPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

I created a List Page that extends a stateful widget.
The List Page gets Posts which I named 'courses' in the firebase.
The posts name 'courses' loads successfully on the emulator together with 'names' and 'images' and 'details' from the firebase. Below is the code for the List page:

```
class ListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListPageState createState() => _ListPageState();
}

class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {
  Future getPosts() async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection('courses').get();
    return qn.docs;
  }

  navigateToDetail(DocumentSnapshot){
   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(courses: courses,)),);

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getPosts(),
          builder: (_, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
              return Center(
                child: Text('Loading'),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {

                    return ListTile(
                      leading: Image.network(snapshot.data[index].data()['img']),
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data()['details']),
                      subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].data()['name']),
                      onTap: () => navigateToDetail(snapshot.data[index]),
                    );

                  });
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

However, the details page is giving me errors when tapped.
I wanted to load the details of every list when tapped from the firebase, but its giving me errors.
The code for the details page is below:

```
class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot courses;
  DetailPage({this.courses});

  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(widget.courses.data()['name']),
          subtitle: Text(widget.courses.data()['details']),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error I get is this:

```
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'courses'.
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(courses: courses,)),);
```

Comment: does ```getPosts()``` returns list of courses?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the argument of the function named las DocumentSnapshot, but not using it. The variable courses is not instantiated inside the function so flutter has no idea what is it.

```
  navigateToDetail(DocumentSnapshot){
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
  DetailPage(courses: ¿¿¿courses???,)),);
  }
```

I think what could work for you is something like this

```
  navigateToDetail(DocumentSnapshot){
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
  DetailPage(courses: DocumentSnapshot,)),);
  }
```

Or change the argument name to courses instead of DocumentSnapshot

GL

Comment: It worked, thank you. So much appreciate this